# Value of temperature at normal temperature and pressure (NTP)

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, definition

I was attempting this numerical from my textbook:

"A definite mass of an ideal gas at NTP is allowed to expand to four times its original volume i) slowly, ii) suddenly. Calculate its final temperature and pressure in each case."

The author has taken the Temperature (T1) at NTP as 0°C, and Pressure at NTP as 76 cm of Hg. But isn't the Temperature at NTP 20°C (293 K)? I would like to know the correct value of Temperature at NTP.

Comment: Normal can also be 15 degrees C.

Comment: I see...I actually googled it and it showed 20°C in some website.  And may I know the correct Pressure?

Answer (score 1):

The normal temperature and pressure (NTP) used by [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) is a temperature of $20\rm \, ^\circ C$ or $\rm  293.15\, K$ and an absolute pressure of $\rm 101.325 \,kPa$.

[$\rm 20 ^\circ C$ - A Short History of the Standard Reference Temperature for Industrial Dimensional Measurements](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/112/1/V112.N01.A01.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If the author is using 0 C, then it should be STP for Standard Temperature and Pressure and not NTP for Normal Temperature and Pressure.

I read that NTP is commonly used as a standard condition for testing and documentation of fan capacities. Aside from that, I'm not familiar with the designation.

Hope this helps.